# Blue burning effect - how do they do it.?

Tags: html, css, blogs

I wanted to make effects similar to the title(**Thought Xpress**) written on [this site's](http://www.xeemez.blogspot.com) **header**. How on earth did we make a effect like that?

I mean, it appears that the name is **burning** and has some ****blueish*** smoke*(blue) above it.

Comment: Inspect the element with `Firebug`, or another debugger depending on which browser you're using. And have a look at the CSS properties that are being applied to it.

Comment: well there's a mess of CSS in blog. I am unable to understand the correct tag used and CSS properties.

Comment: Install `Firebug`, `Right click` on the text, and click `Inspect element with Firebug`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That site is my blog...  Here's the code:

```
#header-wrapper{width:960px;margin:0px auto 0px;padding:24px 0px 23px 0px;overflow:hidden;background:url(some Image) no-repeat;}
#header-inner{background-position:center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
#header{margin:10px auto auto 33%;border:0 solid $bordercolor;color:$pagetitlecolor;float:center;width:46%;overflow:hidden;}
#header h1{color:#FFFFFF;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000,0 0 10px #05B7FF, 10px -10px 15px #05B7FF, -20px -20px 20px #05B7FF, 20px -40px 25px #05B7FF, -20px -60px 10px #05B7FF, 0 -80px 30px #05B7FF, 10px -90px 40px #05B7FF,2px 2px 10px #05B7FF,0 0 1px #05B7FF, 0 0 2px #05B7FF, 0 0 5px #05B7FF, 0 0 5px #05B7FF, 0 0 5px #05B7FF, 0 0 10px #05B7FF, 0 0 20px #05B7FF, 0 0 30px #05B7FF,0 0 10px #FFFFFF,-2px 0 5px #FFFFFF,0 2px 5px #FFFFFF,0 -2px 5px #FFFFFF;margin:0 5px 0;padding:100px 0px 0px 15px;font-family:&#39;Oswald&#39;,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:32px;line-height:32px;}
#header h1 a,#header h1 a:visited{color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none}
```

Note: the fourth line, `header h1`, is the key answer to your query.

---

Note: the `header:visited` is necessary and `header:hover` effect will ruin the effect.

Comment: Actually it also depends on good choice of background image. This effect alone is just a sugar water waiting for tea leaf(bgimage) to drop in it. Right ?!!

Comment: yup that's right. background is important.but css is much more stronger in references.worth a technology :P

Answer (score 2):

It's the text-shadow property.

I've created a fiddle isolating the bit you need, if you're looking to plagiarize it completely:

http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/5QWms/

It's the `h1` tag:

```
h1{color:#FFFFFF;text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000,0 0 10px #05B7FF, 10px -10px 15px #05B7FF, -20px -20px 20px #05B7FF, 20px -40px 25px #05B7FF, -20px -60px 10px #05B7FF, 0 -80px 30px #05B7FF, 10px -90px 40px #05B7FF,2px 2px 10px #05B7FF,0 0 1px #05B7FF, 0 0 2px #05B7FF, 0 0 5px #05B7FF, 0 0 5px #05B7FF, 0 0 5px #05B7FF, 0 0 10px #05B7FF, 0 0 20px #05B7FF, 0 0 30px #05B7FF,0 0 10px #FFFFFF,-2px 0 5px #FFFFFF,0 2px 5px #FFFFFF,0 -2px 5px #FFFFFF;font-family:&#39;Oswald&#39;,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:32px;line-height:32px;}
```

As stated in the comments, it's bit of a mess

There's a generator here: http://css3generator.com
That may help you come up with something a little more original.

Comment: Now I feel guilty for calling it a 'bit of a mess' since the actual blog owner has also posted an answer.....

Comment: :>{p That went Awkward.But it's a mess.that's a fact.